# Grabbing XML but output value just @atribute in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i want grab xml file with simplexml_load_file. when i read simple xml it give value, but when i try read this xml that have many data, the output just like @atribute and not give value. please give me solution why ?. sory for my bad english. i have 2 picture, and code to read it.

```
simplexml_load_file('C://xampp/htdocs/instantSupportXml.xml');
print_r($file);
```

Comment: Can you post an sample of the XML and based on that explain exactly what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: If the tags in the XML have attributes, you can only get them using xpath not plain simplexml.

Comment: this the example output of value @atribute..
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [language] => en-US ) [comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )..

Comment: this get the value, SimpleXMLElement Object ( [tax] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ppn] => 0.1 ) [config] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [cloud] => 1 [print] => STAR ) [print-digital] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [period-order-active-month] => 3 [period-bad-order-month] => 12 [datawarehouse-dashboard-refresh-buffer-month] => 2 ) [business-unit] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => Champion [company-number] => 1 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => Champion Printing [company-number] => 271 )

Comment: @marekful - You don't need to use XPath to get the attributes. It's very possible to do it with SimplXML: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<param>
 <tax>
  <ppn>
   0.1
  </ppn>
 </tax>
 <config>
  <cloud>
   1
  </cloud>
  <print>
   STAR
  </print>
 </config>
 <print-digital>
  <period-order-active-month>
   3
  </period-order-active-month>
  <period-bad-order-month>
   12
  </period-bad-order-month>
  <datawarehouse-dashboard-refresh-buffer-month>
   2
  </datawarehouse-dashboard-refresh-buffer-month>
 </print-digital>
 <business-unit>
  <name>
   Champion
  </name>

Comment: It doesn't work with any XML string. But you are right, what I meant is namespaced attributes.

Comment: Update your _post_ with any extra info. Don't post it as comments.

Comment: this one give @atributes value
<xdm:Device xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" language="en-US">
    <xdm:Information>
        <dd:ModificationNumber>4</dd:ModificationNumber>
        <!-- System ....................................................... -->
        <xdm:Component id="dev1000" componentType="system">
            <dd:MakeAndModel>HP Latex 375</dd:MakeAndModel>
            <dd:Description>HP Latex 375</dd:Description>
            <dd:ProductNumber>V8N83A</dd:ProductNumber>
            <dd:Manufacturer>
                <dd:Name>HP</dd:Name>

Comment: i want to get data HP Latex 375 for example, but still get @atributes.

Comment: i already get the data with add @ in simplexml_load_file, now how i get value HP LATEX 375 in this tag. because if just with tag dd:makeandmodel, it give nothing.
 <xdm:Component id="dev1000" componentType="system">
            <dd:MakeAndModel>HP Latex 375</dd:MakeAndModel>

Comment: this my code..
 foreach ($xml as $b){
  $Modifikasinbr = $b->{'dd:ModificationNumber'};
    echo $Modifikasinbr.'<br />';
  }